# file searching and implementation using ipfs and blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

I  want to store some info and secure it using blockchain. I store it in ipfs and save the ipfs hash in the blockchain. What should I do to maintain the hashes. Suppose, if I need to retrieve document which I stored months ago should I search inside blockchain(if it is possible) or setup another DB like mysql or oracle to store the hashes in tuples so that I can query it and get the hash later.

Answer (score 1):

when you’re storing an ipfs hash in the blockchain, you’re basically storing the direct address to a piece of information stored on your node/machine (or another node at which it’s pinned)
If that is a blockchain like BTC, everyone can see the hash stored there, i.e. can access your information.
This procedure is in no way adding to security of the information itself, only securing the public/permanent and time stamped knowledge of the address leading to the information.
if that’s what you want, then okay.

when you upload a file to ipfs, you can wrap it with a name, but the web interface doesn’t show upload dates.

you could resolve
date -> hash from the blockchain and
hash -> name through ipfs ls

or just store all this information in the process of uploading, which is probably more fun